# Stop bash tab completion from thinking I want to cd into .svn directories

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I have a folder structure that's in subversion.

There are a whole pile of top level directories that have only 1 sub folder. (eg `src/com/example`). Normally when I want to cd into the example folder I can go `cd src/<tab><tab>` since bash will fill in the folder names, since there is only one per folder it goes all the way.

However since that directory structure is now in svn, there's a `.svn` directory in each one, and this means I can't cd as quickly.

If I try `cd src/<tab>` it suggests `.svn` and `com`, as opposed to automatically filling in `com`.

Is there some way to tell bash never to suggest cd'ing into a .svn folder, so that if I tab complete it won't include `.svn`?

Answer (score 8):

I can give you two options. Either of which can be placed in your `~/.bash_profile`.

- Bash uses a variable `$FIGNORE` which defines any suffixes that auto-completion will ignore. There seems to be a catch though, in that it prefixes any value with `*.`. So a setting of:

  ```
  export FIGNORE=.svn
  ```

  Will only ignore directories that have something before the period. And:

  ```
  export FIGNORE=svn
  ```

  Will ignore `.svn` directories and anything else that ends in `.svn`.

  Caveat emptor.
- You can prevent all hidden files and directories from being included in auto-completion:

  ```
  bind 'set match-hidden-files off'
  ```

  But you might not find this suitable.

Comment: interesting, but quite tricky